# Force buddypress groups to be private

Tags: buddypress

I want to give group creators no option to create public or hidden groups. All groups should be private.

So that people still can see those groups but have to be invited or request a membership.

The most simple method would be to hide the radio buttons(see pic attached). But I want to do it using a plugin or php.

So, how can I force buddypress to make each group private?

Comment: You would need to look into buddypress hooks. However if all you need is to hide the radio button, it would be way easier to achieve this with css or jquery. With css you could hide the unwanted button and with jquery you could mark the other as selected by default.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your theme or child theme, create an over-ride of this file:
buddypress\bp-templates\bp-legacy\buddypress\groups\create.php

Then adjust the form markup so that only the Private group radio button is created and it is checked.

Creating theme over-rides:
http://codex.buddypress.org/themes/theme-compatibility-1-7/a-quick-look-at-1-7-theme-compatibility/#overloading-template-compatibility-theme-files